# Installing Heroku on Lucid Lynx reveals missing dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, readline

I am trying to get a Ruby on Rails app hosted free somewhere, and Heroku is looking like my last resource. It is supposed to work on Linux, and the gem installs with no errors, but whenever I run any Heroku command it spits out several errors, all connected, and talking about a failed `require`. I looked it up in the code, and it says:

```
require 'readline'
```

That is it.

I have tried to install every variation of `libreadline` that I can find and think of, but none of it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. However what you can try:

1. Make sure, that `libncurses5-dev` is installed on your system.
2. Look up the directory, where Ruby is installed. Then change to subdirectory `ext/readline`
3. `ruby extconf.rb` will generate a Makefile
4. `make && make install`
5. Try your Heroku command again.

Comment: The problem was that the ext/readline directory was non existent.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but it was rather a hack. I hunted down the readline.so file from where it was installed (in some strange spot) and did a hard link to where ruby was looking for readline, and it worked. Not optimum, and I will definitely try what you guys recommend next time. Thanks